# Is there a name for an algebraic structure like this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

I'm self studying abstract algebra. I see that in rings there's no requirement for a multiplicative inverse.

Is there something similar except with no requirement for an additive inverse. For example, all the non-negative rational numbers. Every number other than 0 has a multiplicative inverse, but no additive inverses. We have both the multiplicative and additive identities. Multiplication is still associative over addition.

Is there a name for such an algebraic structure, and has it been studied the way rings have?

Comment: The word you're looking for is [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) (or if you want multiplicative inverses, then semifield)

Comment: Thanks. Semifield is exactly what I was looking for. How do I accept your answer? I don't see a checkmark anywhere. I'm a new member, does that mean I can't accept answers immediately?

Comment: You can't accept comments as answers: you can always accept answers to your own questions though. If you like, I can post this as an answer

Comment: Ok. Thanks. sounds good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant concept here is [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), or semifield if you include multiplicative inverses.